# Copying 57,000 images script

Tags: windows, powershell

Hello I am currently trying to write a script to copy all images from a within a tree of folders to just one singular folder. I need to take all the images ,about 57,000, and then do some other work to them. I had made a simple command to copy them just fine using Get-ChildItem and piping to Copy-Item. However, this does not take into account duplicate names(which there are a lot of). I need help writing this portion to create some useful way to copy all items and keep their names. I currently have:

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName +(1)+$_.Extension } -PassThru | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\insert user here\temp"
```

I need any info I can get. I know this only adds (1) to the end of the file name but I need to figure out a way to get an index number for all items or something like that. I would also prefer to no rename all the original files just the copies. Thanks!

Comment: If there is a duplicate name, what do you want to happen? Say you have the file `MyImage.png` which you copy, and then encounter another file called `MyImage.png` later on; what should the latter file instead be called? If you encountered a 3rd file (called `MyImage.png`) what would that be called as well?

Comment: Ideally something like MyImage(1).png or something to that effect. I can be anything though. I'd be fine with adding the index of for cycles as that ending number to. Anything that can make these two images different so that it can all be copied to one directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using folders that looked like this (*Folder4 intentionally empty*):

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\YourDirectory\ -Recurse


    Directory: C:\temp\YourDirectory

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        04/03/2020    16:03                Folder1
d-----        04/03/2020    16:04                Folder2
d-----        04/03/2020    16:04                Folder3
d-----        04/03/2020    16:02                Folder4
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 MyImage.png
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 YourImage.png

    Directory: C:\temp\YourDirectory\Folder1

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 MyImage.png
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 MyPhoto.jpg

    Directory: C:\temp\YourDirectory\Folder2

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        04/03/2020    16:04              0 YourImage.png

    Directory: C:\temp\YourDirectory\Folder3

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        04/03/2020    16:04              0 catmeme.gif
-a----        04/03/2020    16:04              0 MyImage.png
```

And wanting to copy the files to the location `C:\Temp\DestinationDirectory`, I ended up with this:

```
$Source = "C:\temp\YourDirectory"
$Destination = "C:\temp\DestinationDirectory"

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -File

ForEach($File In $Files)
{
    $Path = $File.Fullname
    $Name = $File.BaseName
    $Ext = $File.Extension

    $NewPath = "$Destination\$Name$Ext"
    $i = 1
    While (Test-Path -Path $NewPath)
    {
        $NewPath = $Destination + "\" + $Name+ "_" + $i.ToString() + $Ext
        $i++
    }

    Copy-Item -Path $Path -Destination $NewPath

    Write-host "Copied file $Path to $NewPath."
}
```

This loops for each file, recursively. Then it loops over each file, and checks to see if the file already exists in the destination. If it does, it sets adds a suffix to the name (`_1` for the first duplicate). It keeps checking, and incrementing, until it doesn't find a file, and then copies said file.

This ended up with the directory as below:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\DestinationDirectory\


    Directory: C:\temp\DestinationDirectory

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        04/03/2020    16:04              0 catmeme.gif
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 MyImage.png
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 MyImage_1.png
-a----        04/03/2020    16:04              0 MyImage_2.png
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 MyPhoto.jpg
-a----        04/03/2020    16:03              0 YourImage.png
-a----        04/03/2020    16:04              0 YourImage_1.png
```

Comment: I'll have to see how this works out on a massive production like the one I am doing, but this worked for me as well. THANk YOU!

Comment: You're welcome @FireMixtap3 . Please do considering marking this as the solution if it works, then future readers know the answer was helpful and the the problem was solved. You'll also get reputation from marking as the solution; which is really important for getting those early privileges.